# Xamarin iOS MapBox build Confusion

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, mapbox

[image: This is my mapbox lines of code]

When i try to add map box in my view i'm getting this error  (Failed to resolve "System.Void ObjCRuntime.BindingImplAttribute::.ctor(ObjCRuntime.BindingImplOptions)" reference from "Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065") but i commit my lines of codes my project build successfully. I can't any solution on Google and Map Box documentations.

Comment: Did you update your VS and Xcode?

Comment: @LucasZ yes Xcode is update to date.

Comment: https://github.com/martijn00/LottieXamarin/issues/159 Maybe this is useful to you

Comment: @LucasZ i followed that link yesterday but not useful for me.